# Modify an attribute of a class that is in a list of interfaces

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

In the project that I am working, there is a class called schedule that implements a function called ValidateShiftForDay:

```
bool Schedule::ValidateShiftForDay(Entities::Employee &employee, Entities::Shift &currentShift, int day, bool fromMutation)
{

    std::list<std::string>::iterator itContract;

    std::unordered_map<std::string, Entities::Contract> Contracts =
        Helpers::Variables::getInstance().getContracts();
    bool shiftOk;
    std::list<std::string> IdContracts = employee.GetContracts();
    int multiplier = fromMutation ? 0 : 1;
    for(std::string IdContract: IdContracts)
    {
        Entities::Contract& contract = Contracts.at(IdContract);
        if (contract.IsValidShift(currentShift.GetId()))
        {
            shiftOk = contract.ValidateRules(*this, currentShift, day, employee.GetId(), multiplier);
            if (!shiftOk)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

There is another class called Contract. Within this class, there is a list of an Interface

```
class Contract {
 public:
    Contract(std::string Id);
    bool ValidateRules(Schedule &schedule, 
        Shift shift, int day,std::string IdEmployee, int multiplier = 1);

 private:

    std::list<Constraints::IConstrainable*> Rules;
    void UpdateCurrentValue(Schedule &schedule, Shift shift,
                               int day, std::string IdEmployee, int multiplier);
    
};
```

And here we have the implementation of ValidateRules

```
  bool Contract::ValidateRules(Schedule &schedule, Shift shift,
                               int day, std::string IdEmployee, int multiplier)
  {
    for (Constraints::IConstrainable *constraint : this->Rules)
    {
      if (!constraint->CheckConstraint(schedule, shift, day, IdEmployee, multiplier))
      {
        return false;
      }
    }

    UpdateCurrentValue(schedule, shift, day, IdEmployee, multiplier);
    return true;
  }
```

Several classes implement the interface IConstrainable, for example the class Workload.  Workload implements UpdateCurrentValue as follows:

```
    void Workload::UpdateCurrentValue(Schedule &schedule, Entities::Shift shift,
                                         int day, std::string IdEmployee, int multiplier)
    {
        
        if (multiplier == 1)
        {
            currentWorkload = currentWorkload + shift.GetDuration();
        }
    }
```

Whenever this method is run, currentWorkload is increased, but the next time the method is run, the value of currentWorkload is 0 again.

Why is currentWorkload always 0? As you might have imagined, currentWorkload is a private attribute of the class Workload.

Comment: How are you telling when `currentWorkload` is increased and when it's 0 again?

Comment: Also note that `std::unordered_map<std::string, Entities::Contract> Contracts = Helpers::Variables::getInstance().getContracts();` creates a copy.

Comment: What I meant was that, while debugging, the first time UpdateCurrentValue is run, we can see that ```currentWorkload``` is incremented from 0 to the value returned by ```shift.GetDuration();```. The second time this method is run, we can see that ```currentWorkload``` is 0 again. I hope this time I was clear enough.

Comment: @NathanPierson, you were right. This line was the problem: ```std::unordered_map<std::string, Entities::Contract> Contracts = Helpers::Variables::getInstance().getContracts();```. Changing it to  ```std::unordered_map<std::string, Entities::Contract>& Contracts = Helpers::Variables::getInstance().getContracts();``` solved the problem. Now ```currentValue``` is updated correctly. Thanks